# How to Automatically resize the HTA window based on contents

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

I'm creating and error message with an image on left and line of text on the right.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>BINDATA FILE ERROR</title>

<HTA:APPLICATION
    ID="ERROR"
    APPLICATIONNAME="ERROR"
    SysMenu="NO"
    MAXIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
    MINIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
    EXITBUTTON="NO"
    SCROLL="NO"
    BORDER="DIALOG"
    ICON="ekis.ico"
/>


<div class="container">
    <img class="middle-right" src="C:\SCRIPTS\OEE_SCRIPTS\Caution.png" align="left" style="width:150px;height:150px;" >
    
<!-- </div> -->

<!-- <div class="containet"> -->
    <font COLOR ="RED" size="6"  style="font-family:courier new;" align="center"><b>STOT Data Not Updating !</b></font>
    <h2 style="font-family:courier new;" align="center">Please Call / Contact</h2>
    <h2 style="font-family:courier new;" align="center">The Line Technician !</h2>

    
</div>


<script language="vbscript">


    Sub CenterWindow( widthX, heightY )
        self.ResizeTo widthX, heightY 
        self.MoveTo (screen.Width - widthX)/2, (screen.Height - heightY)/2
    End Sub

</script>




</head>
</html>
```

I expect that the window will resize based on its contents.

I already tried to set the window size

```
<script language="vbscript">
    Sub window_onload()
        CenterWindow auto
    End Sub
    
    Sub CenterWindow( widthX, heightY )
        self.ResizeTo widthX, heightY 
        self.MoveTo (screen.Width - widthX)/2, (screen.Height - heightY)/2
    End Sub

</script>
```

I expect the window to resize dynamically based on its contents even it is an image or text or both of them are in the window.

Comment: The window doesn't adapt the size of the content, rather the content adapts the size of the window.